# How to convert avro serialized string to raw byte Array - StackExchange.Redis (C# application)

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, stackexchange.redis, confluent-schema-registry

I have records in a Kafka topic serialized using Avro format.  They are then being moved to Redis (by Redis sink connector) using the ByteArrayConverter format.

In another C# application, I query the Redis to get the value. The value comes back as string

```
var db = _connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase(1);
RedisValue value = await db.StringGetAsync(key);
```

How do I convert the above RedisValue to raw bytes - that can then be used with Confluent Schema Registry Client to de-serialize the data to the desired object?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved. The solution to get the raw bytes before de-serializing is

```
Byte[] byteArray = (byte[])value;
```